# 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment in Django. File is `request.FILE['file']`object (InMemoryUploadedFile type). I create message by `EmailMessage(...)` and then attach file by `message.attach(f.name, f.read(), f.content_type)`.

Sending email fails with given error:
`'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: so, any progress here ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me inside a form definition in `forms.py`

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject='some subject',
    from_email='from_address@some_domain.com',
    to=['recipient1@another_domain.com'],
    body='some html content')
email.content_subtype = "html"
if hasattr(self.files, 'getlist'):
    files = self.files.getlist('document[]')
    for _file in files:
        _file.open()
        email.attach(_file.name, _file.read(), _file.content_type)
        _file.close()
email.send()
```

Where `documents[]` is the name of the input html tag:

`<input name="document[]" id="file" type="file">`